# Case class companion object generation error for compound type

Tags: scala, case-class, compound-type

Defined empty trait Test:

```
trait Test
```

what used in compound type:

```
scala> val a : Int with Test = 10.asInstanceOf[Int with Test]
a: Int with Test = 10
```

and case class with parameter of compound type (like Unboxed Tagged Type):

```
scala> case class Foo(a: Int with Test)
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: AnyRef
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Double => java.lang.Double, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Double to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Double`.
```

But it is perfectly work for:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: List[Int] with Test)
defined class Foo
```

And no problem with method definition:

```
scala> def foo(a: Int with Test) = ???
foo: (a: Int with Test)Nothing
```

Scala version ***2.10.3***

Is it normal compiler behaviour?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5183).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've bumped into one of the cases where Scala's attempt to unify primitives and Objects breaks down. Since `Int` in Scala represents the Java primitive type `int`, it can't have any traits mixed into it. When doing asInstanceOf, the Scala compiler autoboxes the `Int` into a `java.lang.Integer`:

```
scala> val a: Int with Test = 10.asInstanceOf[Int with Test] 
a: Int with Test = 10

scala> a.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: Int] = class java.lang.Integer
```

However, autoboxing doesn't happen when declaring types, so you have to do it by hand:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Integer with Test)
defined class Foo
```

But then the compiler type checker won't autobox before checking the types:

```
scala> Foo(a)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int with Test
 required: Integer with Test
              Foo(a)
                  ^
```

So you would have to declare your variable as `Integer with Test`:

```
scala> val a: Integer with Test = 10.asInstanceOf[Integer with Test]
a: Integer with Test = 10

scala> Foo(a)
res3: Foo = Foo(10)
```

or use a cast when calling the case class:

```
val a : Int with Test = 10.asInstanceOf[Int with Test]
scala> a: Int with Test = 10

scala> Foo(a.asInstanceOf[Integer with Test])
res0: Foo = Foo(10)
```

Comment: `Since Int in Scala represents the Java primitive type int` Not true. Scala uses a mixture of int and Integer for Int, with auto boxing and unboxing. It does not translate directly to int or Integer. As in the comment pointed out, it’s simply a bug in 2.10

Answer (score 2):

as @Travis Brown said This is a know [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5183)，fixed in scala 2.11.7.

run under ammonite Repl 2.0.4 (scala 2.12.10 java 1.8.0_242)

```
@case class Foo(a: Int with Test)
a: Int with Test = 10
```

Comment: You should explain more about your solution.