# Scala Tag Types

Tags: scala, sbt

Using : Scala 2.10.3

Trying to compile the following gives an error. If I remove the case-class then it compiles.

Anythoughts on where the double is being resolved from?

```
object DomainTypes {
type Tagged[T] = { type Tag = T }
trait DeviceIdTag
type DeviceId = Int with Tagged[DeviceIdTag]

implicit class TaggedInt(val data: Int) extends AnyVal {

 def deviceId = {
  require(data >= 1)
  data.asInstanceOf[DeviceId]
}
}
}

 case class DeviceIdHolder(odeviceId:DeviceId)
```

> [error] type mismatch;
>   [error]  found   : Double
>   [error]  required: AnyRef
>   [error] Note: an implicit exists from scala.Double => java.lang.Double, but
>   [error] methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
>   [error] a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Double to any AnyRef.
>   [error] You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Double`.
>   [error] one error found
>   [error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
>   [error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 2, 2014 11:47:01 AM

If you replace the INT's with String's then it compiles, so I don't think there is anything structurally wrong per-se.

Comment: What release version of scala are you using?

Comment: Updated with version. It's probably related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094679/case-class-companion-object-generation-error-for-compound-type

Comment: The message is potentially more helpful under 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21285738/386159.

Ideally, an editor would mark this as a duplicate and point to the question to which I have linked.